# xamarin forms - ios - listview header appearing below where it should... showing whitespace?

Tags: xaml, listview, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

Evening All,

Having an issue with the UI on my ios. Working fine on android -

On Admin page, which shows a list of orders, when user clicks on the '*' to the right of each order it opens a popUp window...showing order details...the issue is with the layout inside the popup

So as you can see from the below images for order details screen. On Android the order details appear as a popUp and everything is nice and tidy in the layout....however same screen on ios results in listview header appearing below where it should...leaving white space at the top of the popup?

tried changing the layout but cant seem to figure it out...does anyone see what I am doing wrong please?
Ta

[image]

```
//AdminPage.xaml
<Button Grid.Column="4" Grid.Row="0" VerticalOptions="Start"  Clicked="ShowMore" Text="*" CommandParameter="{Binding OrderModel_Id}"/>

//AdminPage.cs
 private void ShowMore(object Sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Button button = (Button)Sender;
            string OrderId = button.CommandParameter.ToString();

            PopupNavigation.Instance.PushAsync(new PopupView(int.Parse(OrderId)));
        }

//popUp.cs
 public partial class PopupView 
    {
        public ObservableCollection<OrderDetails_Model> PreviousOrderDetails_ForUser { get; set; }

        OrdersDatabase_Controller RecentOrders_Controller = new OrdersDatabase_Controller();

        public PopupView(int Id)
        {
            try
            {
                InitializeComponent();

                List<OrderDetails_Model> RecentOrderDetails_List = RecentOrders_Controller.GetAllOrderDetails_ById(Id);
                PreviousOrderDetails_ForUser = new ObservableCollection<OrderDetails_Model>(RecentOrderDetails_List as List<OrderDetails_Model>);

                int countOfOrderDetailRecords = PreviousOrderDetails_ForUser.Count;
                int startingHeight = 100;
                var tempHeightofStack_SearchResults = countOfOrderDetailRecords * 40;

                //height of popup is adjusted depending on amount of products in order
                StackSearchResultsOuter.HeightRequest = startingHeight + tempHeightofStack_SearchResults;

                BindingContext = this;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Crashes.TrackError(ex);
            }
        }
    }

//PopUp.Xaml
 <StackLayout x:Name="StackSearchResultsOuter" BackgroundColor="White" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" >
        <StackLayout.Resources>
            <converters:ProductIdToProductNameConverter x:Key="converter"/>
        </StackLayout.Resources>
            <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding PreviousOrderDetailsForUser}" HasUnevenRows="True" SeparatorVisibility="None">

                <ListView.Header>
                    <Frame>
                        <Grid>

                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="30*" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="25*" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="25*" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="20*" />
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                            <Label Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Text="Product"
                           HorizontalOptions="Center"/>
                        <Label Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" 
                       Text="Quantity"
                           HorizontalOptions="Center"/>
                        <Label Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="0" 
                       Text="Price"
                           HorizontalOptions="Center"/>
                        <Label Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="0" 
                       Text="Sub"
                           HorizontalOptions="Center"/>

                            <BoxView Grid.Row="1"
                             Grid.ColumnSpan="4"
                             HeightRequest="1"
                             BackgroundColor="LightGray"/>


                        </Grid>
                    </Frame>
                </ListView.Header>

                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ViewCell>
                            <Grid Padding="10" RowSpacing="10" ColumnSpacing="10">
                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="43*" />
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="8*" />
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="25*" />
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="24*" />
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <Label Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding OrderModel_Id}" VerticalOptions="End"/>
                            <Label Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Text="{Binding User_Name}" VerticalOptions="End"/>
                            <Label Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand" Text="{Binding Product_Id, Converter={StaticResource converter}}"/>
                                <Label Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" Text="{Binding Quantity}"/>
                                <Label Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="0" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" Text="{Binding PriceOf_Item, StringFormat='£{0:0.00}'}"/>
                                <Label Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="0" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" Text="{Binding SubtotalForThis_Item, StringFormat='£{0:0.00}'}"/>
                            </Grid>
                        </ViewCell>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
        </StackLayout>


    </pages:PopupPage>
```

Comment: I see that the iOS screen area is taller. Looks to me like on both platforms, it is popping up "centered vertically". If you make a taller Android emulator, I bet you see the same "symptom"!

Comment: Ahhh interesting...but yes...youre right...ran the app on an ios touch (smaller screen) and it appeared fine....solution was to set the vertical alignment to end...now popUp appears at bottom of screen...in tidy order...would have preferred it to appear in the middle...but this quick fix will suffice. If you want to write up the answer ill mark it correct. Thanks again steve....as a side note...do you know why on IOS the <Listview.Header> appears to have a bold frame highlighting its border? would prefer if I could remove it (to show similar to andriod)

Comment: I've added a more detailed answer, with various ways to adjust vertical position.

Comment: I'm not thinking of any reason for the iOS List.Header bold highlight. If you don't find an existing Q&A that solves that, start a new question with the minimal code that shows the symptom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your screenshots, I see that the iOS screen area is taller.

On both platforms, the default is to pop up "centered vertically" in the screen.

It isn't platform-specific. If you make a taller or shorter android emulator, you'll see that also changes where it is, in a similar fashion.

It looks "wrong" on the taller platform, because its neither neatly tucked just under the original text, nor is it centered in the "blank area" - its the screen itself that it is centering on.

---

To adjust it so it is centered in the blank area, try this:

```
<StackLayout x:Name="StackSearchResultsOuter" BackgroundColor="Transparent" ...
    <BoxView x:Name="InvisibleSpacer" BackgroundColor = "Transparent"
        HeightRequest="80" />
    <ListView BackgroundColor="White" ...
```

Adjust InvisibleSpacer's HeightRequest as needed. To get it exact, on different devices, you'd have to use code behind, and measure height of the "Order User ..." view you are mimicking with this invisible area. Beyond the scope of this answer.

NOTE: For this simple task, the `BoxView` is not needed; you can adjust `Top Margin` instead. I show BoxView, because knowing how to inject a blank area is a useful technique. Unlike a Margin, the BoxView has its own `BackgroundColor`, which is sometimes useful. It also has its own `IsVisible`, so you can control whether it is there or not, based on conditions. (When `IsVisible="False"`, the StackLayout won't allocate any height to it; as if its height were zero.)

---

An alternative way to "make it neat", is to set `StackSearchResultsOuter`'s `VerticalOptions` to "Start" (or "End"), and then set its Top (or Bottom) Margin to push it up or down. So instead of being centered, it would be some fixed offset from top (or bottom), that looks pleasing.

Again, use `BackgroundColor="Transparent"`, so that the margin area is invisible.

Comment: Hey Steve...Yeah I implemented your suggestion of adding the boxview and setting all the background colours...while keeping the vertical alignment as center....this has set the popUp in the center of the screen with no issues. Thank you for taking the time to write that out. Ta